# What is the source/book to learn origin/etymology of sanskrit and Vedic-Sanskrit words?

Tags: sanskrit, etymology, nirukta

As the sanskrit language is created by god and every sanskrit word incorporates a huge amount of Hindu philosophy in it.

So, **I want to know the book or source where I can know about origin or etymology of each sanskrit words**.

Comment: https://ashtadhyayi.com/ . And you're right- not just every word, every letter has meaning. See [Maheshvara Sutras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Sutras)

Comment: You can study Nirukta by Yaskacharya

Comment: @Pandya Are you talking about [this book ?](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/nirukta-of-yaskamuni-with-detailed-explanation-set-of-2-volumes-nzc619/)
I don't see any worlds being broken and analyzed in the book.